# 2 color bars in X and Y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, astronomy

I'm working on some Astronomy code in which I am plotting an Hr diagram, the problem is color is really important here and the X and Y axis both have to be labeled, but the axis is both on different scales. How would you suggest I do this? My current code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=pd.read_csv('Sagittarius_star_cloud.csv')
arr=data['bp_rp']
arr2=data['gp']
X=[]
Y=[]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    X.append(arr[i])
for i in range(len(arr2)):
    Y.append(arr2[i])
fig = plt.figure()
plt.ylim(max(Y), min(Y))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(x=X, y=Y, c=X, cmap='Spectral_r')
plt.scatter(x=X, y=Y, c=Y, cmap='Spectral_r')
plt.colorbar(label="Star Color", orientation="horizontal")
plt.colorbar(label="Star Color", orientation="vertical")
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can ignore the NumPy import I was trying to do some stuff with NumPy arrays, but I did not grasp the concept fully, forgot to remove the import.

Comment: (Just as a side note, `pandas` already includes `numpy`, so it doesn't cost anything to import it again.  You've already paid the price.)

Comment: So in your code, are you trying to set colorbar for two direction at the same time and it's your problem?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to have one that goes in the X-axis and another in the Y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a mapping that works for Hr diagrams(future reference)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
csv_file='Hertzsprung-Russell3_diagram.csv'
data=pd.read_csv(csv_file)
arr=data['bp_rp']
arr2=data['gp']
X=[]
Y=[]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    X.append(arr[i])
for i in range(len(arr2)):
    Y.append(arr2[i])
fig = plt.figure()
plt.ylim(max(Y), min(Y))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(x=X, y=Y, c=X, cmap='RdYlBu_r')#cmap
plt.colorbar(label="Star Color", orientation="horizontal")
lhs,rhs=csv_file.split(".",1)
plt.title(lhs)
plt.show()
```

Comment: As a side note, matplotlib doesn't support 2 color bars in the same X and Y axes, if you want to create it you have to make a custom color bar